# The loghttp module error - strange issue that fills up the Application windows log

Tags: iis, windows-event-log

I have a AWS VM used as web server with IIS.

Recently I noticed the following error that fills up the Application windows log.
The log message is added to Application log every few seconds, and out of the 81000+ log entries, more then 95% is this message.

The message is:

> The loghttp module in the worker process with id 'n' could not obtain custom log data for 'm' requests. The data field contains the error code.

[image]

The worker process ID corresponds with the PID of AppPool worker process for the website
The EventID is always 2308, and the event XML data is as below

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP" Guid="{670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD}" EventSourceName="W3SVC-WP" /> 
      <EventID Qualifiers="49152">2308</EventID> 
      <Version>0</Version> 
      <Level>2</Level> 
      <Task>0</Task> 
      <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-19T12:15:07.733403000Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>10733995</EventRecordID> 
      <Correlation /> 
      <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
      <Channel>Application</Channel> 
      <Computer>EC2AMAZ-EOQ4OLA.MGO.LOCAL</Computer> 
      <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="RequestCount">99</Data> 
    <Data Name="PID">3780</Data> 
    <Binary /> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I did searched the web but I could not find anything with a similar error message.

Any idea where is this coming from, what is its cause and any workaround?

Thank you

Comment: It is related to what custom fields you select to write to log files, and how IIS logging service works internally. Your best option is to open a support case with Microsoft support team.

Comment: We did no customization to IIS logging. Any other idea or suggestions?

Comment: @bzamfir Did you ever resolve this issue? We have the same issue.